# Reading from file in unity forces to crash

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

So i made a login to a game for school project , made a text file called assets and registration is working fine however when reading from this file to get this login and password detail that people have just registered makes the unity editor just give in and i have to force close it in taskmanager here is the code please help me.

```
public void Loginbutton()
{
    string uname = username.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    string pword= password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    string line;
    StreamReader l = new StreamReader(@"Assets/logins.txt");
    line = l.ReadLine();
    bool found = false;

    string logindetails=uname+","+pword;

    while (line !="")
    {


        if (line.Contains(logindetails))
        {

            print("Login Successful");
            found = true;
            break;

        }
        if(found == false)
        {
            print("Login not found");
        }


    }
    l.Close(); 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never read from the `StreamReader` again, resulting in your code being stuck in an endless loop. You should call `ReadLine()` at some point in your `while` loop.

But I suggest, you should not use a StreamReader at all in this case. You may just read all the text into a `string` array and iterate over it, like so:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Assets/logins.txt");

foreach (string line in allLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(logindetails))
    {
        Debug.Log("Login successful");
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

and you should also probably move your found-check below the `while` loop, so it doesn't spam while still checking for a match:

```
if (!found)
{
    Debug.Log("Login not found");
}
```

Note that by using [File.ReadAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8), you don't have to care about open or closed streams at all, because you just receive the result. However, you should also note, that using this method may fill up your RAM, because everything within the file is loaded into memory. But I guess you should be fine in your case.